# Add new Fields in the Store Panel in Store Locator google maps api

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, prototype

I want to add new fields for the store in the left panel. I found that I need to extend this prototype method, but I do not know how to go about it.

```js
storeLocator.Store.prototype.getInfoWindowContent = function() {
  if (!this.content_) {
    // TODO(cbro): make this a setting?
    var fields = ['title', 'address', 'phone', 'misc', 'web'];
    var html = ['<div class="store">'];
    html.push(this.generateFieldsHTML_(fields));
    html.push(this.generateFeaturesHTML_());
    html.push('</div>');

    this.content_ = html.join('');
  }
  return this.content_;
};
```

I need to add fields in the list "fields" above.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you already provided, there's a `fields` variable that I think is where you can include additional fields. Have you tried to add a `String` value to that array? Give it a try.

I think the `html` variable is for the interface of the store locator. Notice that the `fields` are pushed (`html.push()`) into the html.

Found this link showing a [Simple Customized Store Locator](http://www.kelly-carter.com/2014/06/customizing-the-google-store-locators-store-listing/). Also, this [Github Store Locator Reference](https://googlemaps.github.io/js-store-locator/reference.html) might also be useful for you.